# java classpath unix

Tags: java, unix, classpath

> java -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib -classpath
>   /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar:. hwclient

In the above example why is there ":." after the classpath?

Comment: colon is the delimiter of classpath entries, and `.` is the current directory

Comment: @Alex http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/running.html uses ; as a delimiter for Windows... (I found this question because I couldn't figure out how to delimit on Unix and didn't read the above link very well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:` The colon is the classpath separator.

`.` The fullstop is a reference to the current directory

```
-classpath /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar:.
```

Because the classpath overrides the default reference to the current directory the above line adds both /usr/local/share/java/zmq.jar and the current directory to the classpath. Without `:.` there would be no reference to the current directory and the JVM wouldnt find the hwclient class.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html

"The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search path, you must include "." in the new settings."

Comment: The link does not work - Oracle probably moved it. Try this one: [**Setting the class path**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)